# How to prune data in v2.x?

Tags: database, members, delete

EE v1.x had nice tools to prune data. EE 2.x seems to have removed these features.

What I want to do is delete Pending user accounts (never activated their account). I can go through and manually delete them 50 at a time. Not fun. Even less fun when the site gets hit by a spambot.

Are there any add ons that do this? Proven methods that get right into the database?

Comment: I could not tag it with 'pruning' since my rep is too low. Someone care to add that tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A query:

```
DELETE FROM exp_members WHERE last_visit = 0
```

Comment: You'd want to add a check for 'pending' in that WHERE statement if you're going for an SQL Query.

Comment: Good point, thank you.  The site I use this on doesn't validate members manually.

Answer (score 5):

Member data is stored in (at least) 3 tables: `exp_members`, `exp_member_data` and `exp_member_homepage`.

You can use SQL to delete the members from these tables.

The safest way to delete them is to the the member model's `delete_member` method. This will make sure any relevant extensions are also run, clean up all the database tables (eg, if the member had posted an entry or comment) and update any stats.

```
$this->EE->load->model('member_model');
$this->EE->member_model->delete_member( $member_id_array );
```

I've built a very quick plugin to delete pending members here: https://bitbucket.org/ajweaver/ajw_delete_members

(I have tested it, but please **take a database backup** before trying it!)

Comment: Andrew's just awesome. I'm always deleting pending members, will have to give this ago.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little misleading but, there is a 'Delete Selected' option in the drop-down menu on the Activate Pending page.

Answer (score 1):

BrandNewBox has a tool to purge data, http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/purgedata I've never used it to prune members, but have used it to remove records from entries. You could give that a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, my purgedata plugin will only handle entries not members

Comment: I thought that might be true.